# Angular Material component for list of properties?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, material-design, key-value

I would like to achieve a responsive list of properties in Angular with Material Design.

Something like this:

[image]

Where, if the screen gets smaller, the labels appear above the values.

I can built something myself, but I think this is a common problem. What is the correct Material / Angular way to display these?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview with dynamic properties based on screensize or https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview with little bit flexbox

Comment: @danvid thanks for the suggestion. I feel both solutions don't capture the key-value nature very well and make it a bit non-standard (I was hoping for a component that was a natural fit)

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally I did it myself. I ended up using a`DL` definition list as it captures the key-value semantics best with `DT`/`DD` type / details.

For the CSS (this is part of my SCSS), the main gist is to use a `grid` with `grid-column-start`

```
DL {
  font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
  padding-left: 24px;
}

DT {
  color: #777;
  display: inline-block;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  padding: 2px 20px 10px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  @include text-extra-small($color-grey-600);
}

DD {
  display: inline-block;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 10px;
  @include text-body($color-grey-800);

}
@include for-mobile {
  DD {
    grid-column-start: 1;
  }
}
```

[image]